# Download Manager causes high CPU usage on Motorola Razr with stock Android 4.0

Tags: battery, motorola-droid-razr, overheating, download-manager

My Razr (Stock ROM 4.0) is very very hot. After some research I found `com.android.providers.downloads` is responsible, since it's using about 60% of CPU.

I have tried killing it, and it respawns, however what I found to work (for two hours) is clearing the cache and data of the process, and killing it, however something is triggering again.

P.S. I'm not downloading anything, and all my apps are updated (so Play Store is not trying to download updates).

If I freeze this process, the Gmail app crashes.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest CM.

Comment: Actually, I want to do that, however there's no stable release for the xt910, a lot of bugs have been reported :S

Comment: Maybe there is an app that monitors network traffic. You could see if some apps try to download a lot in the background and uninstall those, otherwise you could try a factory reset.

Comment: Is it possible that you have copied A LOT OF files into your sdcard? System maybe try to scan them.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked... finally installed a custom build of CM10 into my razr, camera/flash doesn't work but the phone is stable so far (I have tested it for 2 weeks), my advise is to just format android phones with this problem or install a known ROM.